# This program quits after one invalid input instead of two, how can I fix this?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to enter a set of floating-point values. When the user enters a value that is not a number, I need to give the user another chance to enter the value. If the user enters a non-number a second time, I need to end the loop and output the sum of all entered numbers. The expected output looks like this:

```
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: 2
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: 3
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: f
Enter a number, or another non-number to quit: 1
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: g
Enter a number, or another non-number to quit: g
The total is 6.0
```

```
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: g
Enter a number, or another non-number to quit: g
The total is 0
```

Here is my code:

```
try: 
   #ask user for to input set of floating-point values
   num = input("Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: ")
   
   #keep track of sum, counts of inputs that are not floats
   sum = 0
   count = 0
   
   #while the input is a digit and the non-digit input is less than 2, enter loop
   while num.isdigit() and count < 2:
      sum += float(num)
      num = input("Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: ")
      
      if count == 2 and not num.isdigit(): 
         break
   
   print("The total is ", sum)
   
except ValueError:
      print("Invalid input. Please enter a number")
```

This program outputs 5.0 instead of 6.0 for the first example since it totals the values after one invalid input. What can I change so that it asks the user for another non-number, and continues to add to the total until the  user enters two non-numbers in a row?

Comment: Please review the edits I made to your question. Text is much more readable and accessible than an image, so you should avoid posting screenshots of text when you can post the text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program ends after a single non-numeric input because you check `num.isdigit()` in the `while` condition. As soon as you enter an input for which `.isdigit()` doesn't return `True`, the loop ends.

Instead, consider reading the number in an *infinite loop*, and then deciding what to do with it. Note that `.isdigit()` returns `False` when the string contains a decimal point or a negative sign, which could both be present in valid `float`s. You should instead use a `try..except` to catch the case of non-numeric input.

```
total = 0
non_number_count = 0
while True:
    # Ask for another non-number if non_number_count is nonzero
    # If zero, ask for two non-numbers
    msg_number = "another non-number" if non_number_count else "2 non-numbers" 

    # Use an f-string to create the prompt
    user_input = input(f"Enter a number, or {msg_number} to quit: ")

    try:
        total += float(user_input)
        # A valid number was entered, so reset the count
        non_number_count = 0
    except ValueError:
        non_number_count += 1

    # 2 non-numbers were entered, so break out
    if non_number_count == 2:
        break

print(f"The total is {total}")
```

This gives the desired output:

```
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: 2
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: 3
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: f
Enter a number, or another non-number to quit: 1
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: g
Enter a number, or another non-number to quit: g
The total is 6.0
```

```
Enter a number, or 2 non-numbers to quit: g
Enter a number, or another non-number to quit: g
The total is 0
```

P.S.: I renamed your `sum` variable to `total`. You shouldn't name your variable `sum`, since this causes it to shadow the builtin [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

Answer (score 0):

When the user enters `"f"`, then `num.isdigit()` is false, and it exits the while loop and hits the print.

Rather than storing the input directly in `num`, you can try storing in another variable first, and only adding it to your sum once you're sure it's a digit.